# Geodesic polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

What is the form of the space described by the metric $$ds^2=dr^2+k^2\,\,d\theta^2$$ where $k$ is a constant?

I believe this form of metric representation is in the so called geodesic polar coordinates.

I know that it cannot be Euclidean because that would require $r^2$ in place of $k^2$.

Answer (score 2):

If k is constant this is just the Euclidean metric with one of the directions rescaled. Set $ x=r$ and $y=k\theta$.

Comment: Are you sure about this. The map $(r,e^{i\theta}) \mapsto (r,\theta)$ yields an isometry of $ds^2$ and the flat cylinder $]0,R[ \times S^1_{k}$, the latter being the circle of radius $k$.

Comment: As far as the metric goes, the two look the same. Local considerations don't tell you whether the $\theta$ direction is compact.

Comment: of course you are right, thanks